# how can I disable a button in angular 2 without using a form group

Tags: html, angular

> I just need to enable the button if all the forms is filled and disable it if not

**here is my code : **

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form [formGroup]="OvertimeForm" (ngSubmit)="createOvertime()">
 
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="employee" >Employee:</label>
          <select2 [data]="employee"
          [options]="options"
           [width]="570"
           [value]="employee_value"
           (valueChanged)="changed($event)"
          required>
          </select2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Start Time:</label>
                <timepicker [(ngModel)]="start_time" [showMeridian]="ismeridian" formControlName="start_time" ></timepicker>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="toggleMode()">12H / 24H</button> 
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
                 <label>End Time:</label>
                 <timepicker [(ngModel)]="end_time" [showMeridian]="ismeridian" formControlName="end_time" ></timepicker>
           </div>
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
           <label>Reason</label>
             <textarea class="form-control" name="remarks" id="remarks" rows="3" placeholder="Reason ..."  formControlName="remarks"  required></textarea>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="!OvertimeForm.valid">Add</button>
     </form>
```

> but **[disabled]="!OvertimeForm.valid"** is not working
>   *I use different package like time picker and select 2, they have their own function in getting their values*
>
> this is the code in my component

```
this.OvertimeForm = _fb.group({
    'start_time':       [this.ot.start_time, [Validators.required]],
    'end_time':         [this.ot.end_time, [Validators.required]],
    'remarks':          [this.ot.remarks, [Validators.required]],
    'created_by':       [this.ot.created_by, [Validators.required]]
});
```

}

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.get_employee();
    this.get_UserId();
}



get_UserId(){
    this._auth_service.getUser().
    subscribe(
        data => {
            let user = data; // fetched 
            this.user_id = user.id;
            this.OvertimeForm.value.created_by = this.user_id;
        },
        err => console.error(err)
    );
}

get_employee(){
    let employees = this._common_service.getEmployees().
    subscribe(
        data => {
            this.emp = Array.from(data); // fetched record
            this.employee = this.emp;
            this.employee_value = [];
            this.options = {
                multiple: true
            }
            this.current = this.employee_value;
        },
        err => console.error(err)
    );
}
changed(data: any) {
  this.current = data.value;
  this.OvertimeForm.value.employee_id = this.current;
  this.OvertimeForm.value.start_time = moment(this.start_time).format("HH:mm:ss");
  this.OvertimeForm.value.end_time = moment(this.end_time).format("HH:mm:ss");
  // this.OvertimeForm.valid = true;
  // console.log(this.OvertimeForm.valid);
}   

remarks(event:any){
    let a = event;
    console.log(a);
}


createOvertime(){

    let ot = this.OvertimeForm.value;
    console.log(ot);

    this._OTservice
    .createOT(ot)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.poststore = Array.from(data);
            this.success_title = "Success";
            this.success_message = "A new user record was successfully added.";
            setTimeout(() => {
               this.close();
            }, 1000);
        },
        err => this.catchError(err)
    );
}

private catchError(error: any){
    let response_body = error._body;
    let response_status = error.status;

    if( response_status == 500 ){
        this.error_title = 'Error 500';
        this.error_message = 'The given data failed to pass validation.';
    } else if( response_status == 200 ) {
        this.error_title = '';
        this.error_message = '';
    }
}
//time picker
public toggleMode():void {
this.ismeridian = !this.ismeridian;

}
```

Comment: What about `[disabled]="true"`?

Comment: What about marking form with `#overtimeForm` and trying the same you did.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it doesn't work that way

Answer (score 0):

Replace form tag line with :

```
<form #OvertimeForm=ngForm novalidate (ngSubmit)="createOvertime()">
```

Comment: Its in Angular 2 , @MariaJen

Comment: error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Error in ./OvertimeCreateComponent class OvertimeCreateComponent - inline template:36:28 caused by: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

      Example:

      
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!ngForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `[attr.disabled]="!OvertimeForm.valid"`

Answer (score 0):

use `novalidate` in your form tag.

please find below code for reference.

> OvertimeForm.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myNgForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="saveAsConfirm(myNgForm)">

   ////other elements

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!myNgForm.valid">Save</button>    
</form>
```

hope this will help you.